# Python: Column index error with openpyxl

Tags: python, for-loop, xlsx, openpyxl, file-writing

I have two lists which I want to write to a new `xlsx` file:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=[A,B,C,D]
```

I want `list1` to be dumped to column A and `list2` to column B:

```
COLUMN A     COLUMN B
1            A
2            B
3            C
4            D
```

This is my take on it, but it raises the error: `ValueError: Invalid column index 0`.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.compat import range
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
import os

wb = Workbook() 
newdir=r'C:\Users\MyName\Desktop'
os.chdir(newdir)
dest_filename = 'Trial.xlsx'
ws=wb.active
for r in range(1,5):
    for c in 'A':
       ws.cell(row=r,column=0).value=list1[r]
    for c in 'B':
       ws.cell(row=r,column=1).value=list2[r]
wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

The error points at the last line. What is wrong with it?

Comment: 1-indexing is covered in the documentation.

Comment: Why did I get the down vote? I wish we were forced to give explanations without arbitrarily down voting anyone

Comment: I added a comment after downvoting. You obviously didn't spend much time reading the docs.

But, seriously, who cares that much about being downvoted?

Comment: You might be right. But being this some kind of peer-reviewed system, negative comments can be as constructive as positive ones, so I would appreciate if someone said "look, this is what is wrong with your question...". I could very well surf the depository and downvote all of the questions arbitrarily - what kind of contribution would that be, without giving any explanation? I would suggest this amendment to the moderators - when downvoting, an explanation is compulsory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never used openpyxl, but by looking at [the source](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/_modules/openpyxl/utils.html), it seems that column numbers must be between 1 and 18278:

```
if not 1 <= col_idx <= 18278:
    raise ValueError("Invalid column index {0}".format(col_idx))
```

Therefore, instead of using `column=0` and `column=1`, use:

```
for r in range(1,5):
    for c in 'A':
       ws.cell(row=r, column=1).value = list1[r]
    for c in 'B':
       ws.cell(row=r, column=2).value = list2[r]
```

---

**PS:** `for c in 'A'` and `for c in 'B'`? Perhaps you meant:

```
for r in range(1,5):
    ws.cell(row=r, column=1).value = list1[r]
    ws.cell(row=r, column=2).value = list2[r]
```

Comment: Yes, rows and columns are 1-indexed so that `"A1"` corresponds to `(1, 1)`

Comment: I get this error when amending my code as per your last three lines: `ValueError: Invalid column index A`.

Comment: @FC84: then use 1 and 2 instead of A and B

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer, but it's kind of annoying that there is no way to write more than A-ZZZ columns in an excel file...

Comment: Thank you very much, was stuck for day's never knew there could be limitation like that !